# Record audio from default device on Linux (Raspbian) with arecord

Tags: linux, audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I can record audio with the following command:

`arecord -D plughw:0 --duration=10 -f cd -vv rec7.wav`

And `~/.asoundrc` has this:

```
pcm.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 1
}
```

Also, I can play that recorded file with `aplay rec7.wav`.

The point is, I have make it explicit which device to use when recording. While for playing it works fine without that need. Why?

I would like to record like this `arecord --duration=10 -f cd -vv rec7.wav`. But cannot find a way to make `plughw:0` the default device.

I'm trying this on Raspbian. And I'm using an [external USB mic](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1475).

Answer (score 3):

You are probably getting problems as you are using different hardware devices for capture and playback. In the config file, `pcm` sections specify the PCM device (playback and recording), and `ctl` sections are for setting parameters (control device). Since the Raspberry Pi audio card does not support capturing, the default `pcm` device set in your config file will cause `arecord` to return with an error. To get around this, we can set different default devices in the config file. One way of using different hardware device for playback and capturing is to use the `asym` plugin.

Here's an `.asoundrc` that should work

```
pcm.usbmic {
    type hw
    card 1
}

pcm.playback {
    type hw
    card 0
}

pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm{
        type plug
        slave.pcm "playback"
    }
    capture.pcm{
        type plug
        slave.pcm "usbmic"
    }
}
```

Source ALSA wiki page for [PCM plugins](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html)(see section 'Plugins: asym') and [asoundrc](https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Asoundrc).

Comment: Hy there I did award you the bounty and I think your answer is right in this context. I have an issue though that is still unresolved and I did try the `asym` plugin without any success. Could you maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086259/storing-parameters-in-asoundrc-does-not-apply. I'm happy to award another bounty since this problem is driving me nuts ;-)